# Combination of ResNet and ConvNet

Tags: tensorflow, keras, resnet

I have prepared a CNN model for image colorization:

```
"""Encoder - Input grayscale image (L)"""
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))

...

"""Latent space"""
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))

"""Decoder - output (A,B)"""

...

model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same'))
```

Now i want to use ResNet as feature extractor and merge the output to Latent space.

I have already imported ResNet model as:

```
resnet50_imagnet_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet.ResNet50(weights = "imagenet", 
                           include_top=False, 
                           input_shape = (256, 256, 3),
                           pooling='max')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Encoder

```
"""Encoder - Input grayscale image (L)"""
encoder = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))

...
```

#### Decoder

```
decoder = """Decoder - output (A,B)"""

...
```

Use `tf.keras.Sequential()` to merge all models

```
comb_model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [encoder,resnet50_imagnet_model, decoder]
)
```

Comment: But i need to merge them in the Middle of my CNN.

Comment: Hey, thanks for response. But what i have to do, if i need put my grayscale image into encoder and resnet?

Comment: Please open another question. If the answer solves the above question, please accept the answer to this question.